# I can't get the argument from the pom.xml when I use dockerfile-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, intellij-idea

My project has the structure like this

[image]

I want to build a docker image including the sunhomo_admin.jar. So I add dockerfile-maven-plugin plugin in sunhomo_admin/pom.xml and create a dockerfile
(sunhomo_admin/Dockerfile)。

[image]

[image]
When I execute "mvn clean package", I get the docker image. But the image contains all files in sunhomo_admin/target, not just sunhomo_admin/target/sunhomo_admin-1.0.0.jar

Comment: The documentation: https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven shows tat you should add `ARG JAR_FILE` into `Dockerfile`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Andrey Thanks a lot. I solve this problem with your comment!